Error when printing dkim, dmark, spf and mx records
After registering the new Firewall ports, the script is not correctly printing the DNS records and the completion message.
This is what is printing.
Rules updated
Rules updated (v6)
Registros DNS:
DKIM: _domainkey.avisos.vapomanager.cloud IN TXT "k=rsa; p="v=DKIM1; h=sha256; k=rsa;

The correct option would be for it to print the Dkim DNS record in full, right after Dmark, SPF and MX and then the completion message.
This is the relevant part of the script.
# Configura o OpenDKIM para assinar emails com o domínio fornecido
mkdir -p /etc/opendkim/keys/$DOMAIN

# Gera a chave pública e privada com opendkim-genkey
opendkim-genkey -D /etc/opendkim/keys/$DOMAIN/ -d $DOMAIN -s default

# Extrai a chave pública do arquivo default.txt
dkim_record=$(sed -r 's/.*"(.*)".*/\1/' /etc/opendkim/keys/$DOMAIN/default.txt)
dkim_record="k=rsa; p=\"$dkim_record\""

# Configura o OpenDKIM
cat <<EOF > /etc/opendkim.conf
AutoRestart             Yes
AutoRestartRate         10/1h
Syslog                  Yes
UMask                   002
Canonicalization        relaxed/simple
Mode                    sv
SubDomains              yes
Domain                  $DOMAIN
KeyFile                 /etc/opendkim/keys/$DOMAIN/default.private
Selector                default
Socket                  inet:8891@localhost
EOF
echo "default._domainkey.$DOMAIN $DOMAIN:default:/etc/opendkim/keys/$DOMAIN/default.private" >> /etc/opendkim/KeyTable
echo "*@$DOMAIN default._domainkey.$DOMAIN" >> /etc/opendkim/SigningTable

# Cria o arquivo de serviço systemd para o OpenDKIM
cat <<EOF > /etc/systemd/system/opendkim.service
[Unit]
Description=OpenDKIM
After=network.target

[Service]
User=opendkim
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/opendkim -P /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF

# Recarrega o daemon systemd e inicia o serviço OpenDKIM
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start opendkim

# Gera DNS records para o domínio
dmarc_record='v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:postmaster@'"$DOMAIN"''
spf_record='v=spf1 a mx ip4:'"$(dig +short $DOMAIN)"' -all'
mx_record='10 mail.'"$DOMAIN"''

# Imprime as DNS records
echo "Registros DNS:"
echo "  DKIM: _domainkey.$DOMAIN IN TXT \"$dkim_record\""
echo "  DMARC: _dmarc.$DOMAIN IN TXT \"$dmarc_record\""
echo "  SPF: $DOMAIN IN TXT \"$spf_record\""
echo "  MX: $DOMAIN IN MX $mx_record"

# Reinicia os serviços
systemctl restart postfix dovecot opendkim

# Mensagem de conclusão
echo "Instalação e configuração concluída com sucesso!"

The program should generate the Dkim, Dmark, SPF and MX dns, and restart the systems and then print the generated dns records and the completion message.

It doesn't make a difference, but why do you have '' at the end of the dmarc_record and mx-record assignments?

I can't see any reason why it stops at the echo " DKIM: line. Put set -x at the beginning of the script to see a transcript of everything it's doing.

Instead of switching between single and double quotes, you can put entire values inside double quotes: dmarc_record="v=DMARC1; p=reject; rua=mailto:postmaster@$DOMAIN"

please update the question to show the (correct) expected result

@markp-fuso I think it's pretty obvious, they expect the output of echo "  DMARC: _dmarc.$DOMAIN IN TXT \"$dmarc_record\"" and the lines after that.

@Barmar we're not given the contents of the variables so is the double printing of k=rsa; expected? the output is showing DKIM with no leading spaces while the echo shows 2 leading spaces ... if OP is not expecting leading spaces then we're not looking at the script that generated the output

prior to the line echo "Registros DNS:" consider adding typeset -p dkim_record dmarc_record spf_record mx_record to show us contents of these variables; also add the line type -a echo so we can see what echo is referring to (builtin? binary? function? alias? something else?)

how are you running this script? if running from the command line, does the output hang and you have to ^C to get back to the command prompt? does the terminal hang (and ^C does nothing)? do repeated runs of the script stop at the same exact place after printing the same (wrong) output? is systemctl restart postfix dovecot opendkim being run or is the script halting before it gets to here?  trying to understand if the script is hanging or the output/console is hanging (while the script continues processing)

The way you compute dkim_record doesn't produce a correct record.
